# PHP imagecreatefrompng(file) fails when file is a dynamic image file?

Tags: php, image, dynamic, imagecreatefrompng

Is it possible to use imagecreatefrompng() with a php file that returns a dynamic png image?

eg.

```
<?php
 $IM = imagecreatefrompng('image.php?var=1');
?>
```

where image.php looks something like:

```
<?php
 // code to generate image
 header("content-type: image/png");
 imagepng ( $OUTPUT );
?>
```

At the moment I'm getting a "failed to open stream" error - can this be done? If not, are there any quick & easy workarounds? (that don't involve using image.php to save a .png file for the script to detect instead.)

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: there is no such file, silly.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Oh dude, please help the guy out by giving a detailed answer!

Comment: why so complex structure? ever tried to create an image ONCE, not thousand times, passing it from one script to another?

Comment: My poor boy, to get a detailed answer one have to ask a **detailed question!** And sensible one.

Comment: If you have nothing constructive or helpful to say, you are usually better off keeping your mouth shut.

Comment: *sigh* I *knew* my answer was going to get a downvote from @Col. Shrapnel. After all, answering questions he doesn't approve of is *wrong*

Comment: @Pekka you know that requesting urls from your own site is just stupid. And you know that making such comment will never help - these people *always* knows better, what to to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query parameters `?var=1` work only when requesting a resource through http, not through the file system. To do this, you would have to specify a full URL:

```
<?php
 $IM = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost/image.php?var=1');
?>
```

(If your PHP is configured to allow this)

However, the usually much more desirable way would be to include `image.php` directly and pass `var` to it using a normal variable. That saves you a http request that, even if made locally, spawns a new PHP process.

Comment: Which will only work if the `php.ini` setting `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen